# How to produce a outer frame around a plot

Tags: plotting, graphics

The following question is related to plots and graphics.

For a plot:

```
plot = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
   FrameLabel -> {{"y", ""}, {"x", "Sin[x]"}}, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 20, 
     FontFamily -> "Calibri"}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 800];
```

[image]

How can I produce an outer frame around the plot?, to see/save the following:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you could wrap it using Framed@ ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Code:**

```
(*Sample data*)
plot = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
       FrameLabel -> {{"y", ""}, {"x", "Sin[x]"}}, 
       BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 20, 
         FontFamily -> "Calibri"}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 800];

(*Operation*)
Framed@ plot
```

**Output:**

[image: output of a function]

**Reference:**

[Framed](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Framed.html)